# Fill in the blanks questions in flex using action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex4.5

I need to create a fill in the blanks component dynamically. Question text will be retrieved from XML. For Example (some text ____________ some text). The Underline portion should have a text input. The question text will be dynamically loaded and the position should be aligned based on resolution. Give me some examples and which components should be used for achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a HorizontalLayout with a Label,TextInput,Label.

```
<s:Group>
 <s:layout>
  <s:HorizontalLayout/>
 </s:layout>
 <s:Label />
 <s:TextInput />
 <s:Label />
</s:Group>
```

Comment: I have tried this approach. But If I have a question text that's one and a half line, then the text input should be placed after that text in second line. But Not it will be placed in third line. Any Solutions for this

Comment: @siva if you've already tried this approach, you should *say so in your question*.